# IsDayLightSavingTime method returns different values for same timezone and same time

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5, dst

Following code which checks for a specific time in DST or not returning different values for same time with normal datetime and the one obtained from filetime :

```
var tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var reminderstarttime = new DateTime(2018, 3, 10, 22, 0, 0);
var referencetime = reminderstarttime.AddHours(10);  // ReferencedTime is in DST;

var isRemDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderstarttime);
var isRefDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetime);

var reminderStartTimeToUtc = (ulong)reminderstarttime.ToFileTimeUtc();
var referenceTimeToUtc = (ulong)referencetime.ToFileTimeUtc();

var reminderStartTimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long)reminderStartTimeToUtc);
var referencetimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc((long)referenceTimeToUtc);

var isRemDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderStartTimeFromUtc);
var isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetimeFromUtc);

Console.WriteLine("isRemDstWithNormal: " + isRemDstWithNormal + 
                 " isRefDstWithNormal: " + isRefDstWithNormal + 
                 " isRemDSTFromFileTime " + isRemDSTFromFileTime + 
                 " isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime: " + isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime);
```

Answer (score 2):

Zohar had it mostly correct.  The key point being that `DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc`, like many methods that work on `DateTime`, is dependent on the `Kind` associated with the value.  When `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` is passed, this particular method assumes the input was already in terms of UTC.  However in your code you are creating those values as if they are in terms of the time zone given.

Let's zero in on the culprit:

```
var reminderStartTimeToUtc = (ulong)reminderstarttime.ToFileTimeUtc();
var referenceTimeToUtc = (ulong)referencetime.ToFileTimeUtc();
```

Since both `reminderstarttime` and `referencetime` have `Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified`, their resulting file time values are incorrect.  Specifically:

```
reminderStartTimeToUtc:  131651928000000000
             we wanted:  131652216000000000
            difference:       -288000000000  = -8 hours

    referenceTimeToUtc:  131652288000000000
             we wanted:  131652540000000000
            difference:       -252000000000  = -7 hours
```

As you can see, their values are off by the difference from UTC for each respective date.

Converting them back in your code with `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc` gives back values which *do* have `DateTimeKind.Utc`, which throws off subsequent DST checks:

```
reminderStartTimeFromUtc:  2018-03-10 22:00:00 UTC
  which is equivalent to:  2018-03-10 14:00:00 PST (UTC-8)
               we wanted:  2018-03-10 22:00:00 PST (UTC-8)

    referencetimeFromUtc:  2018-03-11 08:00:00 UTC
  which is equivalent to:  2018-03-11 00:00:00 PST (UTC-8)
               we wanted:  2018-03-11 08:00:00 PDT (UTC-8)
```

Note that the switch from PST to PDT happens at 02:00 PST, so both values are still in standard time.

So how do we get the correct this without a hack?  Simply by making sure our input values are in terms of `DateTimeKind.Utc` before we convert the to Windows file times.  (`DateTimeKind.Local` would work as well, but there's no need to involve the local time zone here)

```
// First convert the DateTime values from their unspecified zone-specific times to UTC
var reminderStartTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(reminderstarttime, tzInfo);
var referenceTimeUtc = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(referencetime, tzInfo);

// Then convert THOSE values to file-times.
var reminderStartTimeToUtc = (ulong)reminderStartTimeUtc.ToFileTimeUtc();
var referenceTimeToUtc = (ulong)referenceTimeUtc.ToFileTimeUtc();
```

The rest of the code will follow correctly as-is, and you will get the expected result.

Note that the wording of these methods is somewhat confusing.  `DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc` means that you are converting to a file time, and that input `DateTime` with `.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified` will be treated as if it were `DateTimeKind.Utc`.  The other method, `DateTime.ToFileTime` treats `Unspecified` kinds as `Local` instead.  But they *both* treat `Utc` and `Local` kinds identically, and they both produce a Windows file-time, which is inherently UTC-based.

Alternatively to the above approach, you could use `DateTimeOffset.ToFileTime` instead.  The offset will be taken into account correctly during conversion to file times.

```
// construct a DateTimeOffset for each value
var reminderStartTimeDto = new DateTimeOffset(reminderstarttime, tzInfo.GetUtcOffset(reminderstarttime));
var referencetimeDto = new DateTimeOffset(referencetime, tzInfo.GetUtcOffset(referencetime));

// then just convert them to file times
var reminderStartTimeAsFileTime = reminderStartTimeDto.ToFileTime();
var referenceTimeAsFileTime = referencetimeDto.ToFileTime();
```

Note there is no `ToFileTimeUtc` here, because there is no `Kind` on a `DateTimeOffset`, so there's only one way to convert it.

One last thing.  Note that `DateTime.AddHours(10)` doesn't honor the DST gap. So while you are talking about 8 AM PDT, there have only been 9 actual hours elapsed, due to the spring-forward gap.  10 actual elapsed hours would be 9 AM PDT.  You can correct for this easily if you keep your values in terms of `DateTimeOffset` types *before* you add the 10 hours.

Comment: Good point in that last paragraph! I never thought about that one before... Good thing I knew who to call for help :-)  +1.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working fine. It is giving this response for Daylight saving is because of Daylight started on 11 March 2018 at 02:00 AM in USA & Canada.

Comment: You misunderstood the question. The OP is mistakenly thinking that  `referencetime` and `referencetimeFromUtc` is the same time, but as I've shown in my answer, they are not.

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Though I still stand by my first version explanation, converting to local time will give the wrong results testing if the time is in fact a day light savings time. I'm not sure exactly why. 
I've played with your code on rextester trying to come up with a solution to this. The best one I've found is quite cumbersome - it involves creating a new `DateTime` instance based on the instance of `DateTime` you get as a result from the `FromFileTimeUtc`:

```
var tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
var reminderstarttime = new DateTime(2018, 3, 10, 22, 0, 0);
var referencetime = reminderstarttime.AddHours(10);  // ReferencedTime is in DST;

var isRemDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderstarttime);
var isRefDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetime);

var reminderStartTimeToUtc = reminderstarttime.ToFileTimeUtc();
var referenceTimeToUtc = referencetime.ToFileTimeUtc();

var reminderStartTimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(reminderStartTimeToUtc);
var referencetimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(referenceTimeToUtc);

var isRemDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderStartTimeFromUtc);
var isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetimeFromUtc);

var referenceTimeFromFileTimeUnspecified = new DateTime(referencetimeFromUtc.Ticks);
var isReferenceTimeFromFileTimeUnspecifiedDTS =  tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referenceTimeFromFileTimeUnspecified);

Console.WriteLine("isRemDstWithNormal: " + isRemDstWithNormal + 
                 "\nisRefDstWithNormal: " + isRefDstWithNormal + 
                 "\nisRemDSTFromFileTime " + isRemDSTFromFileTime + 
                 "\nisRefTimeDSTFromFileTime: " + isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime +
                 "\nisReferenceTimeFromFileTimeUnspecifiedDTS: "+ isReferenceTimeFromFileTimeUnspecifiedDTS);
```

I admit it's probably more a workaround then a solution, but I think I've spent more time on this question then I can afford already. Perhaps someone with more experience datetime, file time and time zones can shed some light on this.

### First version

The problem is that your `referencetime`'s `Kind` property is `DateTimeKind.Unspecified`. If you would specify `DateTimeKind.Local` in the constructor of `reminderstarttime`, you would get accurate results.

See **Remarks** section in the documentation of [`DateTime.ToFileTimeUtc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tofiletimeutc?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_DateTime_ToFileTimeUtc) method:

> The ToFileTimeUtc method uses the Kind property to determine whether the current DateTime object is a local time, a UTC time, **or an unspecified kind of time which is treated as a UTC time.** If it is a local time, it converts the time to UTC before performing the conversion to a Windows file time.

(emphasis mine)

Here is my test code:

```
var tzInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Pacific Standard Time");
// This is the only change, except replacing the space with \n in the Console.WriteLine:
//var reminderstarttime = new DateTime(2018, 3, 10, 22, 0, 0);
var reminderstarttime = new DateTime(2018, 3, 10, 22, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
var referencetime = reminderstarttime.AddHours(10);  // ReferencedTime is in DST;

var isRemDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderstarttime);
var isRefDstWithNormal = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetime);

var reminderStartTimeToUtc = reminderstarttime.ToFileTimeUtc();
var referenceTimeToUtc = referencetime.ToFileTimeUtc();

var reminderStartTimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(reminderStartTimeToUtc);
var referencetimeFromUtc = DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc(referenceTimeToUtc);

var isRemDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(reminderStartTimeFromUtc);
var isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime = tzInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(referencetimeFromUtc);

Console.WriteLine("isRemDstWithNormal: " + isRemDstWithNormal + 
                 "\nisRefDstWithNormal: " + isRefDstWithNormal + 
                 "\nisRemDSTFromFileTime " + isRemDSTFromFileTime + 
                 "\nisRefTimeDSTFromFileTime: " + isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime);
```

And the Results:

```
isRemDstWithNormal: False
isRefDstWithNormal: False
isRemDSTFromFileTime False
isRefTimeDSTFromFileTime: False
```

Comment: But isn't the results wrong here : AddHours(10) gives DateTime as 3/11/2018 8:00:00 AM which is a DST time in Pacific Standard Time?

Comment: That is a problem. I'm checking now.

Comment: But i think, what you said in the answer is correct. As per the implementation comments : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,d7044e3a1eb162f9,references 
FromFileTimeUtc makes DateTimekind of returned datetime object as UTC. So as per IsDayLightSavingTime implemenation, this will be converted to PST first and then will be checked for DST.  3/11/2018 8:00:00 AM when converted to UTC willl be  3/10/2018 1:00:00 AM which is not DST

Comment: Not sure of why the implementation of IsDayLightSavingTime depends on Kind property. It should treat the given time by default as time in the asked timeZone. Isn't it?

Comment: I've edited my answer. However, as I wrote, perhaps someone with more experience in this part of the framework can shed some light on this. So calling @MattJohnson: I think you can probably answer this question better then me. Wanna give it a shot?

Comment: @ZoharPeled - Sure!  See my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

The referencetimeFromUtc.Kind is Utc so it's not in DST. Check out the source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezone.cs,ccfb563c9867b5d0

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_TimeZoneInfo_IsDaylightSavingTime_System_DateTime_), that's wrong. If the datetime.Kind is utc the `IsDaylightSavingTime` converts the datetime to local time before returning an answer.

Comment: Yu Xie, you are referring to documentation of timezone. I'am using TimeZoneInfo here.Documentation : https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs